# AWS - Security Groups - Bulk adding inbound rules for Google Apps Script

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-apps-script, aws-security-group

I have Google IPs range on this file: https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.txt

I want to add it into a security group to allow me to login to our DB from Google App Script.

Is there a way to bulk add inbound rules to AWS - Security Groups or do I have to add it manually, one by one?

Answer (score 1):

Through the web console you will have to add them one at a time.

I highly recommend automating your infrastructure with Terraform, which can [load those IPs from Google](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/netblock_ip_ranges), and then dynamically create [security group rules in AWS](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group_rule) from the list.